# Passing list to another function

Tags: haskell

I have this code which generates prime numbers from 2 to *n*

```
primes :: Integer -> [Integer]
primes n = sieve [2..n]
where
 sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve [x|x <- xs, x `mod` p > 0]
```

How do I pass the `sieve`d list (which has my primes) to another function?

Something like this doesn't work (parse error)

```
someText:: [Integer] -> String
someText (x:[]) = "List starts  with" ++ show x

primes :: Integer -> [Integer]
primes n = sieve [2..n]
where
 sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve [x|x <- xs, x `mod` p > 0]
 someText sieve
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't *pass* something to a function, like some list. That's imperative thinking. What you do in Haskell is, you *evaluate* some function with e.g. a list as its argument. Normally, you'd just leave `primes` as it is and use the result as the argument for `someText`. Like<sup>†</sup>,

```
main :: IO ()
main = print (someText $ primes 100)
```

or simply in the REPL

```
GHCi> someText $ primes 100
"List starts  with2"
```

Of course, you can also redefine `primes` to include `someText`. But obviously, the result will then be a string and not a list anymore!

```
primes' :: Integer -> String
primes' n = someText $ sieve [2..n]
 where sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve [x|x <- xs, x `mod` p > 0]
```

It's probably better not to do this, because such a string is pretty useless when you want to use the prime list in any other way. You can better just invoke the original `primes` function:

```
primes' :: Integer -> String
primes' = someText . primes
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Actually this doesn't work: your function `someText` isn't complete. The pattern `x:[]` *only* matches a list which has exactly one element (this is more handily written `someText [x] = ...`). You want to match on *any* list which starts with one element; do that with the pattern `x:_`.</sub>